# Counting specifically with a for loop

Tags: java

I am making a method where a class of students has a max amount of students allowed. My method adds each student to a new class and repeats itself.

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents.length; i++) { //amounts of students
            totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[count], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
            startingStudentNumber++;
            count++;
            if (count == classes.length) {
                count = 0;
            }
    }
```

`classes` is an Array of the Class, `class`. The Class `class` holds the class name and the amount of students which can be added. Right now it adds every student to the next class.

I would like some guidance on how to count the times a student has specifically been added to a class.

Student:

```
public Student(int studentNumber, Class classNumber, double studentGrade) {
    this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    this.aClass = classNumber;
    this.studentGrade = studentGrade;
}

public int getStudentNumber() {
    return studentNumber;
}

public void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) {
    this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
}

public String getClassNumber() {
    return aClass.getName();
}

public void setClassNumber(Class classNumber) {
    this.aClass.setName(classNumber.getName());
}

public Class getAClass() {
    return this.aClass;
}

public double getStudentGrade() {
    return studentGrade;
}
```

Class:

```
public Class(final String name, final int students) {
    this.name = name;
    this.students = students;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(int students) {
    this.students = students;
}
```

Comment: A student is added once because you're creating a new Student each time you loop... Could you rephrase your question because it is not so understandable...

Comment: @YassinHajaj I have an array of Students which need to be added to classes. Every student is added in a different class. (Student 1 to class a, Student 2 to b). Now, I would like to count the amount of students which has been added to class a.

Comment: If every student is added to a different class then the amount of students added to each class will always be 1

Comment: @MrWiggles when it has reached the end of all the classes, it goes back to index 0 and adds a new student to class a. Until there are no students left.

Comment: You'll have to make a change in your Student class en Class class, could you post both please?

Comment: @YassinHajaj added the classes.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution seems to be on the right track if I understand the problem correctly, however one more change would be to replace

```
totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[count], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
```

with

```
totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[currentClass], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
```

However this will fill each class with students before moving on to the next class, not spread the students evenly amongst classes. If the latter is what you are looking for the loop will be a bit more complicated and the easiest way to do it is to store the number of assigned students somewhere in the class, so you can reference it later and skip to the next class if the one in line is already full.

Comment: This should be a comment under the answer you're speaking about

Comment: It should be but I am  not yet able to add comments to other answers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not declare your students variable of the class Class `final`, then you'll have to call your `Setter` and add one to your `Getter` in your `class` Class.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents.length; i++) { //amounts of students
        totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[count], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
        class[count].setStudents(class[count].getStudents + 1);
        startingStudentNumber++;
        count++;
        if (count == classes.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
}
```

Another option is to create a

```
public void addStudent(){
    this.students += 1;
}
```

And add it to your code like :

```
class[count].addStudent();
```

---

**EDIT 1 :**

> How do I know if a class is full and if I should not add any student?

```
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents.length; i++) { //amounts of students
            if (class[count].isFull()){
                --i;
            } else {
                totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[count], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
                class[count].setStudents(class[count].getStudents + 1);
                startingStudentNumber++;
            }
            count++;
            if (count == classes.length) {
                count = 0;
            }
    }
```

And the `isFull()` method would look something like this :

```
public boolean isFull(){
    return this.students >= maxStudents;
}
```

And maxStudents :

```
private final maxStudents = 25; // For example
```

Comment: Now I know how many Students a Class has, but what if I want to limit my Class to a X amount of students? How would I "shove" the current Student to the next class if this Class is full.

Comment: In this case it will not any student. How can I make it so that the current student will be added onto the next Class?

Answer (score 0):

To add each student to a different class (spread them as evenly as possible amongst all classes instead of filling each class first) you should add another variable to the Class class called `CurrentStudents` or something like this, to hold the number of students currently assigned to the class.

This variable can be updated either from the loop assigning students or from the student class constructor.

Then right after `count++;` add

```
while (classes[count].getStudents()==classes[count].getCurrentStudents()) {
    count++;
    if (count==classes.length) count=0; }
```

This will skip any classes already full. Of course you also have to add a provision that makes sure you don't have more students than space in all classes together, otherwise it will be trapped in an infinite loop trying to find an empty class.

Comment: Do you mean with `getStudents()` to get the maximum amount of Students?

Comment: It seems that is the way you designed the Class class, since you declare this as final, yes, that was my assumption.

Answer (score -1):

If i'm understanding the question right, you could do something like this

```
int currentClass = 0;
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents.length; i++) { //amounts of students
            totalStudents[i] = new Student(startingStudentNumber, classes[count], randomGrade(1.0, 10.0));
            startingStudentNumber++;
            count++;
            if (currentClass >= classes.length) {
              //ran out of room
              break;
            }
            if (count == classes[currentClass].maxStudents){
                count = 0;
                currentClass++;
            }
    }
```

Should work perhaps. Let me know if I'm off the mark here.

Comment: Every student is added to a different class (student 1 to a, student 2 to b, etc.), it would be like this if they were added all together in one class and then onto the next one. I hope you understand the question slightly better now.